# Why does content outside the body still display?

Tags: html

hi I am new to coding as I read in html only the content of the  tag will be displayed but in my case even the content outside the  tag also displaying why is it so? am I doing any mistakes here.

below is the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
        Welcome html learner
    <body>

        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here in scenario 2 the content outside the body is also displaying.

Comment: The code is definitely "wrong".  But different browsers can be *extremely* forgiving about a *wide* variety of HTML coding errors/invalid HTML.  The main "gotcha" for "breaking the rules" is that there's no guarantee the offending code will a) display, b) display the way you intended, and/or c) display consistently from browser to browser.

Comment: some browsers still display this html text. its not well formed.

Comment: @SangamBelose — It is not XML, so the term "well-formed" has no meaning. If it *was* XML then it *would* be well-formed. Every element has a start tag and end tag and then are opened and closed in first-in, last-off order.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your word. I think the well formed term applicable to many markup language including xhtml, html, xml etc.

Comment: @SangamBelose — It is an XML term. It does not apply to HTML (except in HTML 5's XML serialisation). XHTML is an XML application.

Comment: @Quentin I agree that its more widely used in xml, but its moreover applied to markup languages.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element)

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Because browsers are very good at error recovery.

Longer version for this particular case:

The text node after the end of the `head` element triggers the creation of the body element. The start tag for the `body` element is explicitly optional in the HTML specification.

Then the start tag for the `body` element is discarded after copying its attributes to the real `body` element as it can't appear as a child of the `body` element. (See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#in-body) for the specifics).

Consequently, none of the content is outside the `body` element

Comment: validator.w3.org gives a clue: "Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open."

Answer (score -7):

As per Syntax of HTML everything in between `<html>` & `</html>` will be displayed in web page.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. It is definitely wrong, but browsers have grown nice enough to display the html.. Edit your answer and I will remove my downvote